# ROS2 nav2 global costmap disappearing

Tags: ros, ros2, rviz, global-costmap, local-costmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I am using ros2 foxy on Ubuntu 20.04 with rviz2 and gazebo 11.
I'm running a robot in a simulation and will soon test my program on a real robot.

Everything launch and work as intended :

- I can drive the robot with teleop
- I can use nav2 to tell it to go from point A to point B

Now I want to save a map of where the robot has been when driving.
I set up it's footprint so when I move it around, the global_costmap gets "populated" with white cells (if I understand correctly, it means they go from unknown to free).

However, after 3/4 minutes of driving the global costmap disappear with this message :

```
[bt_navigator-11] [INFO] [1654067456.988313971] [bt_navigator]: Begin navigating from current location to (3.10, 1.08)
[controller_server-8] [INFO] [1654067457.016923884] [local_costmap.local_costmap]: Received request to clear entirely the local_costmap
[bt_navigator-11] [WARN] [1654067457.017791003] [bt_navigator_rclcpp_node]: Node timed out while executing service call to local_costmap/clear_entirely_local_costmap.
[controller_server-8] [INFO] [1654067457.018207010] [local_costmap.local_costmap]: Received request to clear entirely the local_costmap
[planner_server-9] [INFO] [1654067457.019795388] [global_costmap.global_costmap]: Received request to clear entirely the global_costmap
[recoveries_server-10] [INFO] [1654067457.023361510] [recoveries_server]: Attempting spin
```

I think it is a normal behavior but is there a way to stop that from happening so I can move around my entire area and then save it as a map for future uses ?
Thank you for taking the time to read my question, feel free to correct anything you think is wrong/inaccurate.

Edit (1) : After more testing, it appear that this happens when the robot get's "stuck" or have difficulties to follow the path it was given.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/401717/ros2-nav2-global-costmap-disappearing/) by [Bastian2909](https://answers.ros.org/users/102337/bastian2909/) on ROS Answers with karma: 68 on 2022-06-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think you should check your Behavior Tree for this Behaviors plugin `Clear Costmap` call:

- https://navigation.ros.org/plugins/index.html#behaviors

> A service to clear the given costmap
> in case of incorrect perception or
> robot is stuck

- https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation2/blob/main/nav2_costmap_2d/src/clear_costmap_service.cpp

If you want to not use it, modifying a BT is the way to go. I recommend Groot for this, it's easier.
https://navigation.ros.org/tutorials/docs/using_groot.html

For the ROS2 Galactic installation:

```
   cd ~/dev_ws/src
   git clone https://github.com/BehaviorTree/Groot.git
   cd ..
   rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src
   colcon build --symlink-install --packages-select groot
```

I have `sudo apt install ros-galactic-behaviortree-cpp-v3` before too.

You have to `source install/setup.bash` and `./build/groot/Groot`.

You can load BT XMLs from the Nav2 repository/your package and modify it.

---

Originally posted by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) with karma: 3064 on 2022-06-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1